# Escaping in Powershell for a git log

Tags: powershell, git-log

I know the escape character is (`), the backtick, but even if I try to use it toe escape the < characters I get error...

```
git log ORIG_HEAD --no-merges --date=short --pretty="format:<tr><td>%h</td><td>%ad</td><td>%an</td><td>%s</td></tr>" > test.txt
< was unexpected at this time.
```

How can I go about formatting my git log as above?

Answer (score 3):

If on PowerShell v3 try this:

```
$out = git log ORIG_HEAD --% --no-merges --date=short --pretty="format:<tr><td>%h</td><td>%ad</td><td>%an</td><td>%s</td></tr>"
$out > test.txt
```

The --% puts PowerShell into a different parsing mode more suitable for native executables.  See this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2012/06/14/new-v3-language-features.aspx) for more details.

If you're not using PowerShell v3, I suggest you use echoargs from the [PowerShell Community Extensions](http://pscx.codeplex.com) to see the arguments as git.exe receives them from PowerShell e.g.:

```
PS> echoargs log ORIG_HEAD --no-merges --date=short --pretty="format:<tr><td>%h</td><td>%ad</td><td>%an</td><td>%s</td></tr>"
Arg 0 is <log>
Arg 1 is <ORIG_HEAD>
Arg 2 is <--no-merges>
Arg 3 is <--date=short>
Arg 4 is <--pretty=format:<tr><td>%h</td><td>%ad</td><td>%an</td><td>%s</td></tr>>

Command line:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\PowerShell Community Extensions\Pscx3\Pscx\Apps\EchoArgs.exe"  log ORIG_HEAD --no-merges --date=short --pretty=format:<tr><td>%h</td><td>%ad</td><td>%an</td><td>%s</td></tr>
```

If you can see how PowerShell is passing the arguments to the exe you have a fighting chance to figure out how to massage the arguments which usually involves using extra quotes.

Comment: Sorry, This is powershell 2